# Application hang with specific parent folder name

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash

I have this environment:

- Windows 7 32bts (Spanish version)
- First weird thing i saw: There are two "Archivos de programa" folders (ProgramFiles).
- The application route: C:\Archivos de programa\Int\BRU"
- The application executable: BRU.exe

Ok.. the first time of the problem (the application was used before this without problems)... the user run the executable and the application crash without any error.. just "BRU.exe has stop working.." message. 
When i saw that there are two "Archivos de programa" folders, what i did was copy the path "Int\BRU*.*" to the other "Archivos de programa" folder. Then, i run the application of that folder and the application WORKED!. Ok.. that was fine.. but only about a couple of weeks, then the user have the same problem with this executable too (the other executable never worked again).
The second move i did was to rename the BRU folder... so i change it to BRU1.. so the path now is: "int\BRU1\BRU.exe". I run the application and it WORKED!. 
A couple of weeks later the user run the BRU.exe (the one in BRU1 folder) and AGAIN crashed with the same problem.
I did the same thing this time changing the folder to BRU2... and it WORKED AGAIN!

So... WHAT IT'S HAPPENING HERE??? i really don't understand what's going on but i never have this problem before.

Comment: My guess is the crash is related to another file in the folder, perhaps a configuraton, data, or resource file. What other files exist in the directory? Does running CCleaner have any impact? user persistent storage for applications references the path of the app, so by changing the path, you may be creating a new config file in your users %appdata% heirarchy.

Comment: The problem is that the application was installed many times in different computers without that problem. The configuration files are fine and no one works with a path.